# What are the gray square icons in the Ubuntu sidebar and how can I remove them?

Tags: gnome, icons, 22.04, dash-to-dock

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 and I'm seeing these gray square icons on the side bar of Ubuntu.

[image: gray square icons in Ubuntu sidebar]

Why are they shown and how to remove them?

Comment: Are you dual booting with another OS?

Comment: Yep, I'm using windows 10 in the same device @Raffa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are disk partitions in your device. In order to disable viewing them in your dock, go to *Settings* → *Appearance* → *Configure dock behaviour* and turn off *Show Volumes and Devices*.

Comment: +1 ... That many volumes are probably from Windows dual boot ... only a guess :-)

Comment: If you want to get rid of those specific disks and not all disks, you can add them to fstab as noauto.  If that's useful, let me know and I'll expand this to an answer.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user10489 I think that this would be quite useful as a new Q&A! From a search I did, I didn't find a question for how to get rid of specific disks.